# Powershell script to upload files to sub folder in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a bunch of files to a folder in my S3 bucket.

The script works if I upload to the root of my bucket:

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -File $file.Name -Key $file.Name
```

However, prefixing the folder to the file path it fails to upload the file:

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -File $file.Name -Key "reports-upload-test\$file.Name"
```

I'm not getting an error in my catch block nor am I getting **Error copying file**

```
try {
    Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -AccessKey $AKey -SecretKey $SKey -Region $region
    Set-Location $source

    $files = Get-ChildItem  | Select-Object -Property Name

    if (Test-S3Bucket -BucketName $bucket) {
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            if (!(Get-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -Key $file.Name)) {
                if ( Write-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -File $file.Name -Key "reports-upload-test\$file.Name" ) {
                    Write-Host "Copying file : $file.Name "
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "Error copying file : $file.Name "
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "The bucket $bucket does not exist."
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the key be "reports-upload-test/$($file.Name)" ?

Comment: @Joe Thanks! that did the trick!

Comment: Note that you can also use the -KeyPrefix parameter to set a common prefix path to all files uploaded, instead of placing it in the -Key parameter value. In conjunction with the -Folder parameter, you can achieve an upload of all files in a folder hierarchy with a single Write-S3Object call instead of a Get-ChildItem/Write-S3Object loop.